# Is there a way of making text hidden in an input box?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have this code of a degrees converter and it works perfectly. But one of my concerns is when I select a degree, say, Celsius, I type my number in and press the button which will give me the temperature in Kelvin and Fahrenheit. But say I want to have another temperature in Kelvin, I type my number in the box and press calculate, it generates the temperature for Fahrenheit and Celsius but it leaves the previous value of Kelvin still in the input box. What I want is, depending on what temperature you choose, it removes that text. For this example, I would've wanted the number given for Kelvin to have disappeared. I've tried "document.getElementById("").style.display = "none"; but all that does is remove the input box. I want only the text to disappear. Is there a way I can do that?

```
    if(temperature == "Fahrenheit") {

      calculate = Math.round((inputValue - 32) * 0.555);
      document.getElementById("Celsius").value = calculate;

      calculate = Math.round((inputValue - 32) * 0.555 + 273.15);
      document.getElementById("Kelvin").value = calculate;

      // hide fahrenheit value

  }

  else if(temperature == "Celsius") {

    calculate = Math.round((inputValue * 0.555) + 32);
    document.getElementById("Fahrenheit").value = calculate;

    calculate = Math.round(inputValue + 273.15);
    document.getElementById("Kelvin").value = calculate;



    // hide celsius value

  }
```

I hope you get what I'm trying to ask, if not I'll try and elaborate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**How to remove input value**

Your question has the answer :). The way you set value to the input field, use the same way to unset the value by setting empty string.

```
document.getElementById("Fahrenheit").value = ""; // set empty string
```

Now do the same for the "Celsius".

**How to hide input value**

Instead of removing, if you want to hide the input value, there is another simple css way to do this:

```
input {
  color: transparent;
}
```

or by javascript:

```
document.getElementById("inputId").style.color = "transparent";
```

Happy Coding :)

Comment: Wow it was that easy haha! Thank you so much, I wish I had thought about that! XD

Answer (score 3):

Try :

```
document.getElementById('#yourSelector').value=""; /* this will clear the text of the control*/
```